# After Effects: Add a Null to a point of two path's intersection

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions, after-effects-scripting

I'm looking to position a null at the intersection of two paths. I'm creating a bending elbow rig with irregular shapes, and I wanted to be able to place something in the crease of the elbow as it moves.

Hopefully this image helps; as the shape rotates, the point at which the intersection of the path changes, and I'd like to be able to automatically track that point of the intersection where the cross is, which follows the slight curvature of the path.

This diagram maybe over complicated by the fact that there are two places where the paths cross (at the back of the elbow) too.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Have you looked at using Duik for rigging? https://rxlaboratory.org/tools/duik-angela/